# Why was Amir Khan's character named PK?

Tags: analysis, character, pk

Can someone please tell me why Amir Khan's character is named **PK** in his Bollywood film, [PK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PK_%28film%29)?

Comment: I have an edition of Charles Dickens' "Pickwick Papers" in which the introduction says that Dickens picked the name "Pickwick" because P and K are the funniest letters of the alphabet.  And that was some years after I worked for a software company named PC-Kwik (my ex-boss got a chuckle from that...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PK is a hindi slang. It expands as 'Pea kay' and it means **being drunk**. Whenever Amir Khan's character talks to the general people, they feel like his statements and questions are absurd and idiotic. So they ask him whether he is drunk (PK), and hence he gets this name.

Answer (score 2):

It's comical usage of the name PK, which is a common name as Pankaj Kumar or Prashant Khare and so on, also means drunk. When he asks questions to people which seem absurd to a common man, they ask if he is drunk (bhai pi ke he ka). And continuosly being asked the same Amir Khan eventually starts believing that maybe he is known as PK on earth, somehow earth people know but he doesn't.